# Symfony3 : Lost values when saving data in database with collection into collection

Tags: sql, forms, entity, symfony, formcollection

I try to create a tree structure for a catalog.

First the user creates the catalog with basic informations (name, code, validity period, type, etc.). Then, I redirect user in another form to create the tree structure.

The catalog can have multiple levels.
The levels can contain multiple products (named here "Model").

So, in my tree form, I have a collection of levels.
And in the level collection form, I have a collection of models.

In other words, **I have a collection into another collection.**

[image]

I don't manage to save my several entities in database. **It losts the model values** (second collection) when I do `$em->flush();` in my controller. I have an integrity constraint violation on the composite key of CatalogModel entity (which is composed of the level id and catalog code).

However, Catalog, CatalogLevel and CatalogModel are well persisted. There are both filled with correct datas.

So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong....

**Catalog Entity** : Note that I don't use an auto generated Id. The Code is the id, and it is provided by the user when he creates the catalog.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="catalogue")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CatalogRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="code", message="Catalog code already exists")
 */
class Catalog
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Catalogue_Code", type="string", length=15)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=15, maxMessage="The code is too long ({{ limit }} characters max)")
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CatalogLevel", mappedBy="catalog", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $levels;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->levels = new ArrayCollection();
    }

   /**
    * Set code
    *
    * @param string $code
    *
    * @return Catalog
    */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

   /**
    * Get code
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Get levels
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getLevels()
    {
      return $this->levels;
    }

    /**
     * Add level
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level
     *
     * @return Catalog
     */
    public function addLevel(\AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level)
    {
        $level->setCatalogCode($this->getCode());
        $level->setCatalog($this);

        if (!$this->getLevels()->contains($level)) {
            $this->levels->add($level);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove level
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level
     */
   public function removeLevel(\AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level)
    {
        $this->levels->removeElement($level);
    }
}
```

**CatalogLevel entity** : I don't use an auto-generated ID either. Level as a composite key composed with level id and catalog code. The id is generated in JS when I create a level with the add button in the form. Remember, levels are a collection form.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="catalogue_niveau")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevelRepository")
 */
class CatalogLevel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Niveau_ID", type="string", length=15)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Catalogue_Code", type="string", length=15)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $catalogCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Niveau_Nom", type="string", length=40)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Parent_ID", type="string", length=15, nullable=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CatalogLevel")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="Niveau_ID", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Niveau_Ordre", type="integer")
     */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalog", inversedBy="levels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Catalogue_Code", referencedColumnName="Catalogue_Code")
     */
    private $catalog;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CatalogModel", mappedBy="level", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $models;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->order = 0;
        $this->models = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param string $id
     *
     * @return CatalogLevel
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set catalogCode
     *
     * @param string $catalogCode
     *
     * @return CatalogLevel
     */
    public function setCatalogCode($catalogCode)
    {
        $this->catalogCode = $catalogCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get catalogCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCatalogCode()
    {
        return $this->catalogCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return CatalogLevel
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param string $parent
     *
     * @return CatalogLevel
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Set order
     *
     * @param integer $order
     *
     * @return CatalogLevel
     */
    public function setOrder($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get order
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    /**
     * Set catalog
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Catalog $catalog
     *
     * @return CatalogLevel
     */
    public function setCatalog(\AppBundle\Entity\Catalog $catalog = null)
    {
        $this->catalog = $catalog;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get catalog
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Catalog
     */
    public function getCatalog()
    {
        return $this->catalog;
    }

     /**
     * Get models
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getModels()
    {
      return $this->models;
    }

    /**
     * Add model
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CatalogModel $model
     *
     * @return CatalogLevel
     */
    public function addModel(\AppBundle\Entity\CatalogModel $model)
    {
        $model->setLevel($this);
        $model->setCatalog($this->getCatalog());

        if (!$this->getModels()->contains($model)) {
            $this->models->add($model);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove model
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CatalogModel $model
     */
    public function removeModel(\AppBundle\Entity\CatalogModel $model)
    {
        $this->models->removeElement($model);
    }
}
```

**CatalogModel entity** : model has a composite key too, composed with code (the code of the Model entity), catalog code and level id.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="catalogue_rayon")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CatalogModelRepository")
 */
class CatalogModel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Modele_Code", type="string", length=20)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Catalogue_Code", type="string", length=15)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $catalogCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Niveau_ID", type="string", length=15)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $levelId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Modele_Ordre", type="integer")
     */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CatalogLevel", inversedBy="models")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Niveau_ID", referencedColumnName="Niveau_ID")
     */
    private $level;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalog")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Catalogue_Code", referencedColumnName="Catalogue_Code")
     */
    private $catalog;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Model")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Modele_Code", referencedColumnName="Modele_Code")
     */
    private $model;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Date_Debut", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    private $beginDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Date_Fin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    private $endDate;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->order = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param string $code
     *
     * @return CatalogModel
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Set catalogCode
     *
     * @param string $catalogCode
     *
     * @return CatalogModel
     */
    public function setCatalogCode($catalogCode)
    {
        $this->catalogCode = $catalogCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get catalogCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCatalogCode()
    {
        return $this->catalogCode;
    }

     /**
     * Set levelId
     *
     * @param integer $levelId
     *
     * @return CatalogModel
     */
    public function setLevelId($levelId)
    {
        $this->levelId = $levelId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get levelId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLevelId()
    {
        return $this->levelId;
    }

    /**
     * Set order
     *
     * @param integer $order
     *
     * @return CatalogModel
     */
    public function setOrder($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get order
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    /**
     * Set level
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level
     *
     * @return CatalogModel
     */
    public function setLevel(\AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level = null)
    {
        $this->level = $level;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get level
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel
     */
    public function getLevel()
    {
        return $this->level;
    }

     /**
     * Set catalog
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Catalog $catalog
     *
     * @return CatalogModel
     */
    public function setCatalog(\AppBundle\Entity\Catalog $catalog = null)
    {
        $this->catalog = $catalog;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get catalog
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Catalog
     */
    public function getCatalog()
    {
        return $this->catalog;
    }

     /**
     * Set beginDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $beginDate
     *
     * @return CatalogModel
     */
    public function setBeginDate($beginDate)
    {
        $this->beginDate = $beginDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get beginDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getBeginDate()
    {
        return $this->beginDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set endDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endDate
     *
     * @return CatalogModel
     */
    public function setEndDate($endDate)
    {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEndDate()
    {
        return $this->endDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set model
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Model $model
     *
     * @return CatalogModel
     */
    public function setModel(\AppBundle\Entity\Model $model = null)
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get model
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Model
     */
    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }
}
```

Then, the forms :

**CatalogTreeType**

```
class CatalogTreeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('levels',     CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'    => CatalogLevelType::class,
                'entry_options'     => array('catalogCode' => $options['data']->getCode()),
                'allow_add'         => true,
                'allow_delete'      => true,
                'prototype'         => true,
                'label'             => false,
                'by_reference'  => false
            ))
            ->add('search',     TextType::class, array(
                'label'                 => false,
                'mapped'                => false,
                'required'          => false,
                'attr'              => array(
                    'class'             => 'search',
                    'size'          => 35,
                    'placeholder'   => 'Search for a model...'
                )
            ))
            ->add('save',       SubmitType::class, array(
                'attr'              => array('class' => 'button-link save'),
                'label'             => 'Validate'
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'  => 'AppBundle\Entity\Catalog',
            // 'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

**CatalogLevelType** (collection)

```
class CatalogLevelType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name',           TextType::class, array(
                'label'                 => false,
                'attr'              => array(
                    'class'             => 'full level-name',
                    'size'          => 35,
                    'placeholder'   => 'Name of level'
                )
            ))

            ->add('id',             HiddenType::class, array(
                'attr'              => array('class' => 'level-id')
            ))
            ->add('parent',     HiddenType::class, array(
                'attr'              => array('class' => 'level-parent'),
                'required'          => false
            ))

            ->add('models',     CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'    => CatalogModelType::class,
                'entry_options'     => array('catalogCode' => $options['catalogCode']),
                'allow_add'         => true,
                'allow_delete'      => true,
                'prototype'         => true,
                'prototype_name'    => '__model_name__',
                'label'             => false,
                'by_reference'  => false
            ))
        ;
    }
```

**CatalogModelType** (collection)

```
class CatalogModelType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('code',           TextType::class, array(
                'label'                 => false,
                'attr'              => array(
                    'class'             => 'full model-field',
                    'readonly'      => true
                )
            ))
            ->add('beginDate',  DateType::class, array(
                'label'                 => 'Begins',
                'widget'            => 'single_text',
                'html5'                 => false,
                'attr'              => array('class' => 'full'),
                'format'            => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'data'              => new \DateTime('0000-00-00'),
                'required'          => false
            ))
            ->add('endDate',        DateType::class, array(
                'label'                 => 'Ends',
                'widget'            => 'single_text',
                'html5'                 => false,
                'attr'              => array('class' => 'full'),
                'format'            => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'data'              => new \DateTime('0000-00-00'),
                'required'          => false
            ))
            ->add('catalogCode',    HiddenType::class, array(
                'data'              => $options['catalogCode']
            ))
            ->add('levelId',        HiddenType::class, array(
                'attr'              => array('class' => 'model-level-id')
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'    => 'AppBundle\Entity\CatalogModel',
            'catalogCode'   => null
        ));
    }
}
```

And **CatalogController**

```
/**
* @Route("/catalogs/{code}/tree-structure", name="catalog_tree")
*/
public function treeAction($code, Request $request) {    
    // get catalog from database
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $catalog = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Catalog')->find($code);

  // catalog doesn't exist
  if (!$catalog) {
     throw $this->createNotFoundException('No catalog found for code '. $code);
  }

    // build the form
    $form = $this->createForm(CatalogTreeType::class, $catalog);

    // Form posté et valide
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($catalog);     // save the catalog

        // save the levels
        foreach($catalog->getLevels() as $level) {
            // var_dump($level);
            $em->persist($level);

            // save the models
            foreach($level->getModels() as $model) {
                // var_dump($model);
                $em->persist($model);
            }
        }

        // update database
        $em->flush();

        // success message
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Catalog tree structure has been created successfully !');

        # redirection
        // return $this->redirectToRoute('catalog_tree_edit', array('code' => $code));
    }

    // show page
  return $this->render('catalogs/tree.html.twig', array(
     'h1_title'  => 'Tree structure of the catalog : ' . $catalog->getName() . ' (' . $catalog->getCode() . ')',
        'form'      => $form->createView(),
        'code'      => $catalog->getCode()
  ));
}
```

Results of var_dump :

```
// save the levels
foreach($catalog->getLevels() as $level) {
    // var_dump($level);
    $em->persist($level);

    // save the models
    foreach($level->getModels() as $model) {
        // var_dump($model);
        $em->persist($model);
    }
}
```

Level :

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel)[2610]
  private 'id' => string 'NIV_1' (length=5)
  private 'catalogCode' => string 'CATEST' (length=6)
  private 'name' => string 'genou' (length=5)
  private 'parent' => null
  private 'order' => int 0
  private 'catalog' => 
    object(AppBundle\Entity\Catalog)[2493]
      private 'code' => string 'CATEST' (length=6)
      private 'name' => string 'Catalogue de test' (length=17)
      private 'type' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
      private 'promo' => null
      private 'tariff' => string 'F0' (length=2)
      private 'campaign' => string 'FTEST' (length=5)
      private 'beginDate' => 
        object(DateTime)[2495]
          public 'date' => string '2016-06-16 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      private 'endDate' => 
        object(DateTime)[2496]
          public 'date' => string '2016-06-24 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      private 'catalogSalesForce' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[2473]
          private 'snapshot' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          private 'owner' => 
            &object(AppBundle\Entity\Catalog)[2493]
          private 'association' => 
            array (size=15)
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[2086]
              ...
          private 'backRefFieldName' => string 'catalog' (length=7)
          private 'typeClass' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[2489]
              ...
          private 'isDirty' => boolean false
          protected 'collection' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[2484]
              ...
          protected 'initialized' => boolean true
      private 'forces' => null
      private 'levels' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[2459]
          private 'snapshot' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'owner' => 
            &object(AppBundle\Entity\Catalog)[2493]
          private 'association' => 
            array (size=15)
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[2086]
              ...
          private 'backRefFieldName' => string 'catalog' (length=7)
          private 'typeClass' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[2468]
              ...
          private 'isDirty' => boolean true
          protected 'collection' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[2442]
              ...
          protected 'initialized' => boolean true
  private 'models' => 
    object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[2708]
      private 'elements' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\CatalogModel)[2735]
```

Model :

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\CatalogModel)[2735]
  private 'code' => string 'BARACCBA' (length=8)
  private 'catalogCode' => string 'CATEST' (length=6)
  private 'levelId' => string 'NIV_1' (length=5)
  private 'order' => int 0
  private 'level' => 
    object(AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel)[2610]
      private 'id' => string 'NIV_1' (length=5)
      private 'catalogCode' => string 'CATEST' (length=6)
      private 'name' => string 'genou' (length=5)
      private 'parent' => null
      private 'order' => int 0
      private 'catalog' => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\Catalog)[2493]
          private 'code' => string 'CATEST' (length=6)
          private 'name' => string 'Catalogue de test' (length=17)
          private 'type' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
          private 'promo' => null
          private 'tariff' => string 'F0' (length=2)
          private 'campaign' => string 'FTEST' (length=5)
          private 'beginDate' => 
            object(DateTime)[2495]
              ...
          private 'endDate' => 
            object(DateTime)[2496]
              ...
          private 'catalogSalesForce' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[2473]
              ...
          private 'forces' => null
          private 'levels' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[2459]
              ...
      private 'models' => 
        object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[2708]
          private 'elements' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
  private 'catalog' => null
  private 'model' => null
  private 'beginDate' => 
    object(DateTime)[2722]
      public 'date' => string '1905-05-05 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 1
      public 'timezone' => string '+00:00' (length=6)
  private 'endDate' => 
    object(DateTime)[2772]
      public 'date' => string '1905-05-05 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 1
      public 'timezone' => string '+00:00' (length=6)
```

Request details :

```
"START TRANSACTION"
Parameters: { } 

INSERT INTO catalogue_niveau (Niveau_ID, Catalogue_Code, Niveau_Nom, Parent_ID, Niveau_Ordre) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Parameters: { 1: NIV_1, 2: CATEST, 3: genou, 4: null, 5: 0 } 

INSERT INTO catalogue_rayon (Modele_Code, Catalogue_Code, Niveau_ID, Modele_Ordre, Date_Debut, Date_Fin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Parameters: { 1: null, 2: null, 3: NIV_1, 4: 0, 5: '1905-05-05 00:00:00', 6: '1905-05-05 00:00:00' }
```

I don't understand why model values are lost... Please help !

PS : If I create just levels in my tree, with no models, levels are saved in database. No error. So, I have a problem with models.

Comment: Have you tried cascade = persist on the related entities?

Comment: Can you be more specific ? I added cascade={"persist", "remove"} on $levels collection in Catalog entity and $models collection in CatalogLevel entity.

Comment: Strange, if your `var_dump` is showing that `$level->getModels()` contains models, and you're sure that persist is called on each model then maybe it's not related. Do you get any errors? Maybe you could attempt to reduce the problem to the most simplest case to help debugging, e.g. inside the controller instead of using forms manually create each entity, set the relations and try persisting them.

Comment: Yes I persist each model just after persisting each level, if you look at the "results of var_dump" part of my post.
Since few days, I'm doing it differently. I think Symfony or doctrine doesn't like collections into collections... I decided to separate levels and models creation/modification.
I will have 1 form for add/edit level and 1 form for add/edit model. For now, add/edit levels works well. I hope it will be the same for models. Thank you for your help.